# Parameter count mismatch error in RestSharp?

Tags: c#, .net, restsharp

```
public IRestResult Send(MessageEnvelope envelope)
{          
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddBody(envelope);
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    var responce = _restClient.Execute(request);
    return new RestResult
    {
        Success = responce.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK,
        ErrorMessage = responce.Content
    };
}
```

When I pass the `envelpoe` value I had a runtime error call

```
Parameter count mismatch
```

in the line containing `request.AddBody(envelope);`.

(when I add values to `AddBody` method).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Our solution was to replace the default serializer with JSON .NET

I used the instructions here: 
https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/readme.txt

However, you now have to set the serializer on the request and not at the client.

```
// Use JSON .NET serializer
request.JsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
```